# Can I represent matrix as a number

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

This may be a very simple problem for you guys.

I want to reprsent whole matrix as a single number. For example,

say I've a 3*3 matrix as follows:

[ 1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9 ]

Can I represent this matrix as a single number?

Having asked this question, let me tell you why I want to do this.

I've 2 matrices, and I want the difference of 2 matrices as a single number. What I actually want is to **find out how different/similar 2 matrices are represented by a single number (rather than a matrix).**

Comment: it depends on the size of each matrix element

Comment: I dont really get what you mean by 'represent matrix by single number' could you tell more about what you need the 'single number' to be, like sum of numbers in matrix or something else

Comment: You might want to read up on [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) and the natural distance measures that can be realized with them.

Comment: @monster i need to find out how similar/different 2 matrices are represented as a number.

Comment: There are many  of these! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm **but** if what you want is to quantify the *difference* between two matrixes with a single number, subtract them and then evaluate the result’s matrix norm. This will be much more reliable than subtracting the norms of the matrixes. If you want a single recommendation, just use the Frobenius norm, so `Frobenius(matrixA - matrixB)` (requires both matrixes be the same size of course).

Comment: the simplest way is storing the whole matrix as a 9-digit decimal number, which fits within 32-bit int, if each element is 1-digit only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole family of functions that take a matrix and produce a scalar number: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm If you just want a simple recommendation, use the Frobenius norm. In Python:

```
import numpy as np
frobenius = lambda matrix: np.sqrt(np.sum(matrix ** 2))
```

(Or, just use `scipy.linalg.norm(matrix, 'fro')`! See [scipy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) docs, which lists the many norms it supports.)

Now. If you want to quantify the similarity **between** *two* matrixes as a number, use the norm of the difference:

```
frobenius(matrix1 - matrix2)
```

(**Don’t** take the norms first and then subtract them, that’s not a reliable way to measure matrix distance. (I.e., `frobenius(matrixA) - frobenius(matrixB) # BAD BAD BAD!`.))

Answer (score 1):

You want the difference between two matrices as a single number. So you don't want to represent the two matrices as one number then take the difference - that would work, but it's destroying information.

If the matrices are the same size, take root mean squared deviation. a{0][0] - b[0][0] squared etc. Then sum, take the mean, and the square root (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bijective function `f` from the space of matrices to the set of natural numbers:

```
f: M -> N
```

You can implement this approach algorithmically using a hash function.

Comment: If the goal is to represent the distance between matrixes as a scalar, then you absolutely don’t want to use a hash.

Comment: Cool image for you, Ayoub Falah.  Love the Mandelbrot set.  Nice answer, too.

Comment: @AhmedFasih "The distance between matrices" I don't know this term, I also think that is not right from a mathematical standpoint, because distance is a real number, but the difference of two matrices gives a matrix of the same type( There is an answer, where the poster discusses his approach under "if both matrices have the same size" that does not make any sense because if they don't have the same type then the difference is not defined. Anyway, the problem is the map a matrix to a number: I don't understand the postcondition of your "implication".